Exposing a custom API - Security Practices to consider suggestion
I'm constructing a prototype external web app form that will create a lead in Salesforce and making it available to the public. Web app will use the integration user from salesforce, and that user will be used for authorization.
I created the integration user and configured the permission settings with the fewest permissions; I also configured the connected app. Is there anything that has to be addressed or set up to prevent potential attacks/risks? I'm developing it as if I'll be releasing it to the public.
Any specific suggestions for my project? I am not sure whether this a dumb approach. :D

The security-first approach to development is considered a best practice. After all, it's easy to keep an app secure if that's your design goal, but it's a nightmare to try and bolt on security as an afterthought. Remember, if you make a session ID public, then anyone can do anything they want as if they were that user. Make sure that the permissions are as limited as possible. Every field, every object, every sharing rule. This may include reassigning the records to a different user after creation, so the integration user can't view/modify the records later, etc.
